# How to make a responsive box inside a responsive image in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive box inside a responsive image in Bootstrap 4 but the problem is, when I add 100% of `width` to the box It stretches after the image, and if I add `right` property of 15px to the image it doesn't stretch but instead, when I zoom out to the 33% or low in the google chrome browser the box gets out of the image.

Another problem is When I zoom out to 33% or low the logo gets too small but it doesn't stay with the same height as the navbar.

I also did some research and found that in bootstrap 3 there was no problem doing that with a simple div, but doing the same with Bootstrap 4 the box stretch.

[fiddler](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wav4x5n6/6/)

[image: zoomed out website]

Answer (score 0):

You have set 100% width for your div class **.sborder** and you have given a left-margin of 15px as well. This is making the div go outside of image.

Use css calc() method to set the width of **.sborder**

check out the below code and **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wav4x5n6/8/)**

```
.sborder{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
/*right:15px;  doesn't work when the screen is zoomed out*/
width:calc(100% - 30px);
left: 15px;
height: 40%;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: red;
color: #fff;
padding:0;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the late respone, Unfortunately, it didn't work when I zoom out with a widescreen size the box starts to stretch outside of the image again I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add overflow in the image? I think what you need for the image was `overflow: hidden;` before the box. So the box will hide when it come out from the image content.

Comment: how adding overflow: hidden in img will affect another element?

Comment: It will hide the content under the image when image `position: relative` as I remember from some css-tricks article

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It didn't work the box just disappears and I need it to be absolute.